# Plotting the region $ -1 < Re(z) \le 1$ and $ -\pi/2 < Im(z) \le \pi/2$ before and after being transformed by $w=e^z$

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, conformal-geometry

Can someone please verify that my diagram plot based on the calculations below is correct -Thanks.

$$w=e^z=e^x\cos(y)+ie^x\sin(y)$$

$$\implies u=e^x\cos(y)\space and \space v=e^x\sin(y) \tag{1}$$

> $$for \space -1 <\Re(z) \le 1  \space \space i.e. \space \space 1 < x \le 1$$

$$\dfrac{u^2}{e^{2x}}+\dfrac{v^2}{e^{2x}}=1$$

$$=\dfrac{u^2}{e^2}+\dfrac{v^2}{e^2}=1 \space \space and \space \space \dfrac{u^2}{e^{-2}}+\dfrac{v^2}{e^{-2}}=1 \space for \space x=1 \space and \space x=-1 \space respectively$$

> $$for \space -\frac{\pi}{2} <\Im(z) \le \frac{\pi}{2}\space \space i.e. \space \space -\frac{\pi}{2} < y \le \frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$\color{green}{0<cos(y)<1 \space \space and \space \space -1<sin(y)\le1}$$
*from $(1)$ i deduce the following:*

$$\therefore \space 0< u \le e  \space \space and \space \space -e < v \le e$$

[image]

Comment: The picture doesn't seem to meet the requirements. Since the orange area has $\operatorname{Re}$ as bounds $\frac{-\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$...

Comment: woops!, i have uploaded what i initially planned on uploading, does it look ok?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem right.

As you noted:
$$w(z) = e^z = e^x\cdot (\color{red}{\cos y+i\sin y})$$

Note that the last part is the equation of a unit-circle since $\color{red}{\cos y+i\sin y} = e^{iy}$.

Since $y\in {\left]\frac{-\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2} \right]}$ you know the map goes to the right part of a circle.

How about the radius?

$$\text{the radius = } e^x \in {\left]\frac{1}{e}, e\right[}$$

You get the following:
[image]

Comment: What did you use to make this, Geogebra?

Comment: @GFauxPas Geogebra rocks ;)

Comment: @dietervdf shouldn't the radius of the inner circle be $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$, can you maybe also tell me where i can find some good geogebra tutorials.

Comment: Why would it be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$? $e^x$ is minimal on the interval $[-1,1]$ at $e^{-1}$... I don't know any Geogebra tutorials, the program seems pretty self-explanatory.